# RSA list index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption

I am trying to make a cipher that at the end it encrypts it with RSA. Here is what I have so far.

```
key1 = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDVTHc4bPSCRefmW+X4+Rsg11I/JwS1ukQdwKpPu62Nm6H/tB1cFT4q0Efs/AlIIC7IdqzgKjsawnl4C/5v19icQ7QIcXToqwh2Wz9hyrRZqurjaFAYY1HYsk0eCBldQu26OEhqZUKLX6txhiKxx0zYJ64xFkpDbOsX4vYa1uyKowIDAQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
key2 = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDIN2AAg0uDw5UP1w1O4V5vBl43L0eH+n5ZJPZlglaq4Clxxb4MPj1996v9P96MgWwktDI4mByJ1FPdhbigRalx79NgASsE4hkzacHdjNwxFaUo4tGFQZZdkRGUpzs4QdsNwazCZg8HJrRnlHnwd2q8yj/sklp0N2OaqgCY0pGrhQIDAQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
key3 = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDdBKY+qU/TgxZ7Lh1RuRvpcq80NJhONVutSammvvW0zcwHl0tSMmbBwEOC5sOZX25gYEH0alTDrnTFxSDXntDJAq5UU00SZ12RA2+mIxnWW2YPVapWYGtwGLK9bY2jDsAo368PdsUa6xB4U1jLqft59l36ZJEtllaeImWh7oVt+wIDAQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
key4 = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDCDfdeIATXyHi5DUwFL0qi7IApbrocq9eEEAn6KsdIJAMo429lM3k0K94/TtCE5238OEGa9UUYmsm8Opja1qGW6qwqLyw+HEfRcBGE1Py2YSTIeJOitiQScjMfS+9tq6kgoUdySu8MCFup7Umf2y/yYghVBWjOfBH2mGmp6cCyUwIDAQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
key5 = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCfOyGZU//BMWbHODlUbVgnlcjnGlun9VyAdPSo6AzIcGOxWeiIXZMNsT7HT3Ah+Y7+Q+bKLMahwJhjKkzsTO4pRGPX/OHl6F7c27YFPbUVUypZd9aJUQI5EpQXu+3UHYNR7VQ1tgSh1O8UYTG6wdXZuwDJypPZ/iHPOdN2nRSqKwIDAQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
import os
import time
import random
import Crypto
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random
codedsentince = ""
count = input("how many WORDS? ")
if count == int(count):
    for number in range(0, count):
        codedword = ""
        letters = 0
        word = raw_input("enter a word? ")
        def fib(number):    
            if number == 1:
                return 1
            elif number == 2:
                return 1
            else:
                return fib(number - 1) + fib(number - 2)
        for letters in range(0, len(word)):
            letter1 = chr(ord(word[letters]) +fib(letters + 1))
            codedword = codedword + letter1
        for letters in range(0, len(word)):
            letter1 = chr(ord(word[letters]) +fib(letters + 1))
            codedword = codedword + letter1
        for letters in range(0, len(word)):
            letter1 = chr(ord(word[letters]) +fib(letters + 1))
            codedword = codedword + letter1
        codedword = " " + codedword
        codedsentince = codedsentince + codedword
print codedsentince
keynumber = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
firstkeynumber = random.choice(keynumber)
if firstkeynumber == 1:
    firstkeynumber = '1'
    key = key1 
elif firstkeynumber == 2:
    firstkeynumber = '2'
    key = key2
elif firstkeynumber == 3:
    firstkeynumber = "3"
    key = key3
elif firstkeynumber == 4:
    firstkeynumber = '4'
    key = key4
elif firstkeynumber == 5:
    firstkeynumber = '5'
    key = key5
private_key = RSA.importKey(key) 
print(private_key.exportKey())
public_key =private_key.publickey()
with open("rsa.pub", "w") as pub_file:
    pub_file.write(public_key.exportKey())

with open("rsa.pvt", "w") as pvt_file:
    pvt_file.write(private_key.exportKey())
with open('rsa.pub', 'r') as pub_file:
    pub_key = RSA.importKey(pub_file.read())

encrypted = pub_key.encrypt(codedsentince, None)
print(encrypted)
print("there will be a txt file in the same directory for you to read the encrypted string of words. This file will made after pressing enter. Also it will be deleted 1 min after pressing enter")
raw_input()
text_file = open("encryptedfile.txt", "w")
text_file.write(codedsentince)
text_file.close()
for i in xrange(60,0,-1):
    time.sleep(1)
    print i
os.remove('encryptedfile.txt')
```

My error is in line 57 with this exact error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "encryption.py", line 55 in <module>
    private_key = RSA.importKey(key) 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 638, 
    importKey if lines[1].startswith(b('Proc-Type:4,Encrypted')): 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

However when I just run the RSA part I don't get a error. The RSA part is listed below:

```
import Crypto
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

#Quick way to generate a new key
private_key = RSA.generate(1024)

#Show the real content of the private part to console, be careful with this!
print(private_key.exportKey())

#Get the public part
public_key = private_key.publickey()
with open("rsa.pub", "w") as pub_file:
    pub_file.write(public_key.exportKey())

with open("rsa.pvt", "w") as pvt_file:
    pvt_file.write(private_key.exportKey())

#Load public key back from file and we only need public key for encryption
with open('rsa.pub', 'r') as pub_file:
    pub_key = RSA.importKey(pub_file.read())

#Encrypt something with public key and print to console
encrypted = pub_key.encrypt('hello world', None) # the second param None here is useless
print(encrypted)
```

I am using Python2.7.3 With Crypto2.6.1 Installed on Windows 7.

Comment: Please refer to my updated answer on your previous question about RSA.

Comment: well what is different between your code and mine?

Comment: the main difference is that you paste the key into the code, have you tried loading the keys from files? besides, why do you paste the key into the code then write it out to file then load it back again?